# Widlar current source : get \$ I_{C1} \$?

Tags: current, source, widlar

from the Widlar schema
[image]
that you can see, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widlar_current_source), i don't know how to retrieve this formula :
$$ I_{C1} = {\beta_1 \over {\beta_1+1}} \left( I_{R1} - {I_{C2} \over \beta_2} \right) $$

Comment: The formulas mean little when there's no **schematic** to relate them to. Sure, I can follow the link and look there but I'm too lazy so include it here. And what is your actual question?

Comment: What can't you retrieve?

Comment: your first formula differs from that in the article you link to.

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve is this formula (corrected) : $$ I_{C1} = {\beta_1 \over {\beta_1+1}} \left( I_{R1} - {I_{C2} \over \beta_2} \right) $$. I put the schema too...

Answer (score 2):

Ok , I get the solution :

With these formulas :
[image]

from
[image]

and KCL in A and after in B :

$$ I_{R1} = I_{C1} + (I) $$
$$ I_{R1} = I_{C1} + (I_{B1}+I_{B2}) $$

i get

[image]

Comment: Please accept your own answer (by clicking the tick button right under the points) so that the question does not remain open.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that a \$Q_1\$ is a diode-connected BJT thus, without \$Q_2\$ we see that:

\$I_{R1} = I_{B1} + I_{C1} = I_{E1}\$

And now if we add \$Q_2\$ we have:

\$I_{R1} = I_{E1} +I_{B2} =I_{E1} +\frac{I_{C2}}{\beta2}\$

but you want to know the \$Q_1\$ collector current:

\$I_{E1} = I_{R1} - I_{B2}\$

\$I_{C1} = \alpha*I_{E1}\$

\$I_{C1} = (I_{R1} - I_{B2})*\alpha\$

Additional we know that

\$\frac{I_C}{I_E} = \alpha = \frac{I_B *\beta }{I_B*\beta + I_B} = \frac{\beta}{\beta +1} \$

therefore

\$I_{C1} = \alpha \left(I_{R1} - I_{B2}\right) = \frac{\beta}{\beta +1}\left(I_{R1} -\frac{I_{C2}}
{\beta2}\right)\$

Comment: I am not ok with you: $$I_{R1} = I_{C1} + I_{B1} + I_{B2} $$

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: The response is in my answer (modified)

Comment: Well you see two nodes but I see one "big" node os this must be true Ie1 = IR1 - Ib2 no matter how many nodes you add.

Comment: Without Q2 ! Yes : without Q2...i read a little quick...